# Impossible to define dynamic content (mc:edit) when creating a Campaign from a template with V2 API

Tags: php, api, mailchimp

I am using Mailchimp API v2, with the appropriate php wrapper.
The need is quite simple:
1 - Create a campaign from an existing template
2 - Send the campaign

My problem is that I CAN NOT create any content in sections (called mc:edit) from that API, altough according to documentation, it IS possible.

On Mailchimp account, this is part of the template

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateBody">
    <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="bodyContent">

                    <!-- // Begin Module: Standard Content \\ -->
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                    <td valign="top">
                                            <div mc:edit="content_tdm_body></div>
                                    </td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- // End Module: Standard Content \\ -->

            </td>
    </tr>
```

As you can see, my editable content key is `content_tdm_body`

And this is the php code I use:

```
$cid = $api->campaignCreate('regular', 

                             array('list_id' => "xxx", 
                                   'subject' => "A campagin test",
                                   'from_email' => "x@y.com",
                                   'from_name' => "TDM",
                                   'template_id' => "xxx"),

                             array('sections' => array('content_tdm_body' => "TEST")));

$campSendStatus = $api->campaignSendNow($cid);
```

Obviously, the campaing is created, the mail is sent, BUT the content remains definitely empty.

Anyone facing this kind of problem? What am I missing?

Comment: Does it work if you do a create with no sections and then add those in a subsequent update?

Comment: Smart suggestion. Yes, I tried, but this does not work either. During this test, I also updated plain text content to check if update was really applied: Plain text is well created / updated; but HTML sections remain empty

Comment: For those who are interested in API V2 php wrapper, a good one is available here https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Got it. I assumed I was using API V2 php wrapper. After digging into the php wrapper sources, I found out that it was the API V1.3 wrapper, so I was using a deprecated API, which does not support HTML sections for Campaign creation from template. –